Maximal Eigenvalues of Simultaneously Diagonalizable Matrices
I am considering a sequence of symmetric and simultaneously diagonalizable matrices. Let $(M_{n})$ be a set consisting of $n\times n$ matrices, defined as the following:
$$
M_{2}=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\right\}
$$
$$
M_{3}=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right),
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\right\}
$$
$$
M_{4}=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right),
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)，
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\right\}\\
\vdots
$$
I proved that for each $n\ge 2$, all the matrices in $M_{n}$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, say by $P_{n}$.
I noticed that for each $n\ge 2$, the maximal eigenvalue of all matrices in $M_{n}$ occurs at the same place. That is, the entry of maximal value of
$$
P^{-1}AP
$$
is the same, for all $A\in M_{n}$.
Here is the question:

Why it is the case?
What is the theoretical implication? In general, what does it mean for a collection of simultaneously diagonalizable matrices having the maximal eigenvalues at the same place?

Thank you very much in advance!

For question 2, there really isn’t much to be said here. They just happen to have the same eigenvector for their largest eigenvalues. That’s all there is to it.

Can you give a more detailed description of these sets of matrices?

It could be that these matrices are basis elements of a fusion ring. (This is the case with $M_2$ and $M_3$.) In that case it is known that the matrices have a common eigenvector corresponding to the Frobenius-Perron eigenvalue.

@DanielArreola Thanks! Can you elaborate a little bit on the last sentence?

@Apple See sections 3.1 - 3.3 of Tensor Categories by Etingof et al. Proposition 3.3.6 is what you'll be interested in. This is only useful if the matrices are coming from a fusion ring though. Could you give a description of how you constructed these collections? They seem to be related to fusion categories coming from representations of quantum groups at roots of unity, but I can't say more unless I know what $M_n$ is in general.
